# trying to populate a cell label with a string from an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

So, I have a cell with one label inside.  I am trying to populate that label text with the various items in my array - all strings.
My array

```
var restauranttypelist: [String] = ["American", "Asian", "Bakery & Deli",
"Burgers", "Italian", "Mexican", "Seafood", "Steakhouse"]
```

and my cell label text

```
  let type = restauranttypelist [indexPath.row]
        var typecell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellone") as RestaurantTypeCell

        typecell.restaurantTypeLabel.text = restauranttypelist.text

        return typecell
```

I have tried a number of solution ranging from ".text" seen above, to ".String", to "restauranttypelist:indexPath.row" to no avail.

I suppose I have two questions.  Am I setting up my array correctly?  Do I need to insert the "[String]" portion after the variable name?

Finally, how would I be able to set the cell label to the numerous items I have in my array?

Thanks for any help... beginning.
Jon

Comment: I think it should be typecell.restaurantTypeLabel.text = type;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In let `type = restauranttypelist[indexPath.row]` you're accessing a String from your Array and storing it in `type`. Therefore, all you need is `typecell.restaurantTypeLabel.text = type`.

There's nothing wrong with how you setup the array. You don't need the `[String]` type annotation since it can be inferred from the value you are assigning to it, but having it there does no harm.

Finally, this doesn't affect how your code works, but it's nice to know anyway:

Swift variable names follow the convention of starting with a lowercase character, and then capitalizing every subsequent word. Following that convention your variable names should be `typeCell` and `restaurantTypeList`.